# Tried to enable the CSS module but error is displayed

Tags: css, reactjs, module

```
    { test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            //sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'

          }),
          sideEffects: true,
        },
```

I tried the above code but I got the error as:

```
 Failed to compile
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
```

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `modules` options to:

```
    { test: cssRegex,
      exclude: cssModuleRegex,
      use: getStyleLoaders({
        importLoaders: 1,
        //sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        modules: {
          mode: "local",
          localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]"
        }
      }),
      sideEffects: true,
    },
```

Comment: Working example using the same config above: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-css-modules-v2

Answer (score 0):

Your getStyleLoaders() function looks like:

```
use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            modules: {
              mode: "local",
              localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          })
```

This resolve issue for me.

my 'css-loader' version is:

```
"css-loader": "3.4.2",
```